# Adding Image as Plane

Tags: image, import

[image]

On the side of the lego block I want a picture as shown in the image below.
I added the image as a plane
I resized the plane and then added the shrink wrap modifier
When I move the lego piece the image stays where it is.

I cannot find any instructions on how to apply a picture to the surface of a flat object.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you parented it to your lego brick ?
If not -> select you plane, shift+select the lego brick, hit Ctrl+P and Set the parent to object

Comment: You can also try to go through shader to add your image as part of a material and place it in the same place (using UVs for example) without having to deal with an extra mesh and modifier

Comment: i would recommend using a shader node for that because a parented object isn't needed for that and might cause problems with z-fighting

Comment: Thank you, didnt know to set the parent.

Comment: Use the image in an Image Texture in your material?

Comment: Did not want to go into using modes. It needs to be simpler than that and using nodes open a whole can of worms for a beginner

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a shrinkwrap modifier is required. You can simply position the 'sticker' (the image as plane) direct in front of the part of the lego brick that it needs to 'stick' to, and add it to lego object so the brick and the sticker become a single object.

To position the image correctly, please try the following:

- Firstly, remove the shrinkwrap modifier
- In object mode, select the lego brick
- Press Tab to enter Edit mode
- Select the face you would like to attach the image ('sticker') to
- Press Shift+S > Cursor to selected
- Tab into Object mode and select the image ('sticker')
- Press Shift+S > Selected to cursor

This will position the sticker in exactly the same position as the face of the lego brick. This will result in some Z-fighting, so you will want to move the image forward by a tiny amount on the X axis:

- In Object mode, select the plane object.
- Press G, then X, then hold Shift and move the mouse a small amount away from the lego brick

Finally, in Object mode, select both first the image as plane, then the lego brick, and press CTRL+J to add the image to the brick object. Now when you move the brick, the sticker will follow.

Answer (score 0):

I know, especially for beginner, Blender is overwhelming and seems to be to complicated to ever understand a thing...but if you keep on learning it you will soon learn how amazing Blender is and IT'S FREE!!!

So if you use this material setup:

[image]

you can choose the image in the image texture node.

Also set it to "clip".

[image]

After that you might see something like this:

[image]

which is of course not what you want.

So click on UV editing:

[image]

Hovering your cursor on the right window, press A to select all vertices:

[image]

now just use your mouse to rotate your view like this:

[image]

then choose: UV -> project from view

[image]

if you now select "rendered view" you can already see parts of the image.

All you have to do now is adapt the UV coordinates on the left window like this:

Select A to select all UV coordinates, press S and scale and move your mouse so that the picture appears as you like it.

[image]